# How can you curve the faces of a hexagon?

Tags: modeling

I'm quite a noob at Blender (this is for 2.8 by the way), and I was hoping somebody could help me figure this out. I've been trying to make a 3D hexagon with the side faces curved inwards to sort of look like a six sided star, but I can't quite figure out how to do it. I've tried to delete the top and bottom faces, loop cut the side faces, add an empty plane axes, and then add a simple deform modifier to the side faces with the empty as the origin, but that didn't quite work out properly. The idea was that it would curve all faces in equally and then I could add the top and bottom faces back.

Here's kind of the shape I want. It's not quite symmetric since I'm not very good at drawing things, but I'd like for the actual result to be symmetric. Thanks for any help!

[image: A rough look as to what I want]

Answer (score 3):

1. create a simple hexagon
2. Edit mode, subdivide as many times as you need for details but an odd number to get a vertex centered on each edge.
3. Select the central vertex
4. turn on proportional editing, spherical mode
5. scale down all selected vertex while adjusting the proportional editing effect radius.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That's exactly what I needed.